# Database optimization: What's faster searching by integers OR short strings?

Tags: database, database-design, performance

I am wondering about a basic database design / data type question I am having.

I have a porjects table with a field called "experience_required". I know this field will be always populated from one of these options: intern, junior, senior, or director. This list may vary a bit as time evolves but I don't expect dramatic changes to the items on it.

Should I go for integer or string? In the future when I have tons of records like this and need to retrieve them by expeirence_required, will it make a difference to have them in integers?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go for Integer over String.

Performance will be better, and your database will be closer to being normalized.

Ultimately, you should create a new table called ExperienceLevel, with fields Id and Title.  The experience_required field in the existing table should be changed to a foreign key on the other table.

This will be a much stronger design, and will be more forgiving in the case that you change the experience levels available, or decide to rename an experience level.

You can read more about Normalization [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: How would choice of integer or string make anydifference to the normalization of the database?

Comment: @Larry: You're right, it won't be, unless you make a foreign key. I have changed the offending sentence - thanks :)

Comment: Even with a foreign key, the implementation detail of using the natural text key or a surrogate integer key would not affect the degree of normalization (or the quality of the design) of the database.

Answer (score 2):

You may like this field indexed. Once indexed Integer and small Char String don't have much (read negligible) performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Integers. Strings should IMHO only be used to store textual data (names, addresses, text, etc).

Besides, integers are in this case better for sorting, storage space and maintaining.

Answer (score 1):

In theory integers will take less memory when you index them.
You can also use enums (in mysql) which look like strings but stored as integers.

Comment: +1 for suggesting enums. Most databases support them (in PostgreSQL they take 4 bytes on disk iirc)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter.  The difference would be negligible.  What difference there is would favor the choice of integer, but this is one of the few cases in which I prefer a short text key since it will save a JOIN back to a lookup table in many reporting situations.

Answer (score 0):

To muddy the waters some, I'll suggest a mix. Start with @GregSansom's idea (upvoted), but instead of integers use the `CHAR(1)` datatype, with values I, J, S, and D. This will give you the same performance as using tinyint, and give the extra advantage of a simple to remember mnemonic when (if) working directly with the data. With a bit of use, it is trivial to remember that "S" means "senior", whereas 3 does not carry any built in meaning--particularly if, as you suggest, extra values are added over time. (Add Probationary as, say, 5, and the "low rank = low value" paradigm is out the window.)

This only works if you have a very short list of items. Get too many or too similar, and it's hard to work up usable codes.

Of course, what if these are sequential values? Sure sounds like it here. In that case, don't make them 1,2,3,4, make them 10, 20, 30, 40, so you can *insert* new categorizations later on. This would also allow you to easily implement ranges, such as "everyone < 30" (meaning less than "senior").

I guess my main point is: know your data, how it will be used, how it may or will change over time, and plan and code accordingly!

Comment: Not downvoting, but this makes it harder to query for 'select * from ... where rank >= ~senior~' for example ... EDIT: you've just included the part about the 10, 20, 30, 40 ranges: I honestly think that's not the best thing to do.

Comment: How the data will actually be used in this particular situation is not clear, so I just presented several ideas I've used in the past